# spring boot cannot create tables in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

Database is created and
@Entity annotations are added to the model classes
also the port number is correct
but when I launch the server then the application, the database still empty.
Here is the Application.properties file:

```
######################################## Database Properties ########################################
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/redditClone?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
######################################## Mail Properties ########################################
spring.mail.host=smtp.mailtrap.io
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=d22d13e85d72db
spring.mail.password=cf28cdab38ef52
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
```

and the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.sid</groupId>
    <artifactId>reddit</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-reddit-clone</name>
    <description>Reddit clone project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

when I've turned off the server and I dropped the database I got an error while launching the application, so the connection is correctly created ...
Does anyone have an idea please ?

Comment: Can you show a class, where entity defined?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing below properties

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=`update`

If this doesn't work check your base-package for ComponentScan or EntityScan includes your entity class package.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved
it was an issue in the package names
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJlnr.png)

I've added `org.sid.` (the same as @SpringBootApplication class) and it worked.
Thank you.